# size parameter cannot be negative

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, amasty

I have problem with elasticsearch on catalog category pages. For some reasons on some pages i have this error:

`Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[size] parameter cannot be negative, found [-137]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[size] parameter cannot be negative, found [-137]"},"status":400} in /vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:693`

Version of Magento is 2.4.3-p3 and for Elastichsearch version is 7.17.12

I am using Amasty Improved Layered Navigation and Amasty Elastich Search modules.

After reindexing data everthing back to normal and no error

Any idea why this error is showing?

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you definately:

https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-cluster-block-exception-magento-2/

And if you can do, then you can reset the index by using this command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

and then run Re-indexing.

OR you can use this query in the database:

```
UPDATE indexer_state SET status = 'valid';
```

Comment: I don't see a connection in this post with the error I am experiencing. My error doesn't involve disk space issues, and when I run indexer:reindex, I don't encounter any errors. Once the indexer finishes, my error disappears from the page.

Comment: Have you tried this

Answer (score 0):

You need to test that your elasticsearch is properly configured or not.
To test your elasticsearch, log in your ssh and run

```
curl http://localhost:9200
```

If its not working please check the elasticsearch setting in the database core_config_data table.
Using below query

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path like '%elastic%'
```

if settings not found you can run below command to set elasticsearch configurations.

```
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname ELASTIC-HOSTNAME
```

**Default is localhost**

```
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port ELASTIC-PORT
```

**Default port is 9200.**

After then run indexer command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```